# Using Robolectric, how to init and finalize stuff before and after all test methods in a test class is ran

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric to do unit testing. I have a test class say `MainActivityTest`, which has several test methods:

```
@RunWith(...)
@Config(...)
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        //...
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        //...
    }

    // other test methods
}
```

I want to execute a method(init method) only once before any test method is executed, and another method after all test methods are executed. How can I do that?
I know I can solve the first question by calling the init method in the constructor, but how can I solve the second question?
I know that I can subclass my Application class and use that Application, But that's kind of awkward for me since I'm using AndroidAnnotations and the real Application class I'm using is final, and I only want to do this in this test class, rather than all test class. I wonder if there is better way to do this.

Comment: Take a look to `@Before` and `@After` annotations in junit

Comment: The `@Before` and `@After` annotations are used to annotate a method that will run before or after each test method is ran, rather than once for all of the test methods.

Comment: Can you share what are you going to do in these methods?

Comment: @Eugen Martynov Sure, I want several test methods to share the same MockWebServer, so that I don't have to start and shutdown the server for every test method.

Comment: Do you mean local web server or something that comes from robolectric

Comment: No, I use [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`.

Note that the methods they annotate have to be static.

See:

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html

So for example:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeEverything() {
    // runs just once before all tests
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    // runs before every test
} 

@After
public void breakdown() {
    // runs after every test
}

@AfterClass
public static void afterEverything() {
    // runs just once after all the tests
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for. Although the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods must be static, but it seems that every test method has its own test class instance, so the `static` does makes sense.